# Maps with WMS layers on top(Online and Offline) - Android

Tags: android, maps, wms

So I need a library that lets me load a Base Map layer (basic terrain), with WMS layers on top of the base layer (Drainage, Cadestal, etc), with a layer of markers that are clickable and display a small overlay with two options to click on. I need this to work in Offline mode too. Can anyone suggest a library to use.

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207501/working-with-geoserver-and-openlayers-in-android/207503

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do those GIS operations in Android using the [QField for QGIS Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.opengis.qfield&hl=en_GB)

It's an open source project, so if you want to build your own see [opengisch/QField on GitHub](https://github.com/opengisch/QField)